# Teamcity git checkout fails with: "Low-level patch stream is closed"

Tags: git, teamcity

I am using teamcity server  8.0.3 (build 27540) and have set up several github.com projects. I added a new project with the only major difference being that this one is password protected, and to solve that I issued a password and username under the root VCS settings.

> But during building I get the following error in my teamcity log:
>   [2013-11-20 21:45:57,287]   INFO [rmal executor 1] -
>   jetbrains.buildServer.VCS - Building clean patch for caching:
>   root="example" {instance id=50, parent internal id=50, parent
>   id=booking_log_ client, description: "#master"},
>   toVersion=5e7db24835bbd67df8f67ef768403b2685a6d4c9, checkoutRules=+:=>
>   [2013-11-20 21:45:57,288]   INFO [rmal executor 1] -
>   Triggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport - Build patch in VCS root "example"
>   {instance id=50, parent internal id=50, parent id=example, descrip
>   tion: "#master"} to revision
>   5e7db24835bbd67df8f67ef768403b2685a6d4c9  [2013-11-20 21:46:01,798]
>   WARN [rmal executor 1] -      jetbrains.buildServer.VCS - Failed to
>   build patch for build #7 {build id=6155}, VCS root: "example"
>   {instance id=50, parent internal id=50,  parent id=example,
>   description: "#master"}, due to error: Cannot
>   build patch: java.io.IOException: Low-level patch stream is closed 
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsRootVcsException: Cannot build patch:
>   java.io.IOException: Low-level patch stream is closed
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer.buildPatchForRoot(PatchComposer.java:117)
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer.buildPatch(PatchComposer.java:10)
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildTypeImpl.buildPatch(BuildTypeImpl.java:335)
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.BuildStarter$2.call(BuildStarter.java:6)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by: jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: Cannot build patch:
>   java.io.IOException: Low-level patch stream is closed
>           ... 8 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Low-level patch stream is closed
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.patches.LowLevelPatchBuilderImpl.assertClosed(LowLevelPatchBuilderImpl.java:141)
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.patches.LowLevelPatchBuilderImpl.writePair(LowLevelPatchBuilderImpl.java:29)
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.patches.LowLevelPatchBuilderImpl.fail(LowLevelPatchBuilderImpl.java:40)
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer.buildCleanPatchToStream(PatchComposer.java:71)
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer.access$200(PatchComposer.java:126)
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer$2.constructPatch(PatchComposer.java:5)
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.SmallPatchCache.getCachedCleanPatch(SmallPatchCache.java:46)
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchCacheImpl.requestCachedPatch(PatchCacheImpl.java:2)
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer.getOrMakeCacheableCleanPatch(PatchComposer.java:174)
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer.makeCleanPatch(PatchComposer.java:170)
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer.makePatch(PatchComposer.java:89)
>           at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.projectSources.PatchComposer.buildPatchForRoot(PatchComposer.java:40)
>           ... 7 more [2013-11-20 21:46:09,922]   INFO [ical executor 1] - .buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges - Collecting changes for VCS root "example" {instance id=50, parent internal id=50, parent id=example,
>   description: "#master"} from state
>   RepositoryStateImpl{defaultBranch=refs/heads/master,branchRevisions={refs/heads/master:
>   5e7db24835bbd67df8f67ef768403b2685a6d4c9, refs/heads/staging:
>   c4eead312a950ea9393e689933728ec92a075c9c}} to state
>   RepositoryStateImpl{defaultBranch=refs/heads/master,branchRevisions={refs/heads/master:
>   5e7db24835bbd67df8f67ef768403b2685a6d4c9, refs/heads/staging:
>   c4eead312a950ea9393e689933728ec92a075c9c}}  [2013-11-20 21:46:09,928] 
>   INFO [ical executor 1] -      jetbrains.buildServer.VCS - Finish
>   collecting changes succesfully for VCS root "example" {instance id=50,
>   parent internal id=50, parent id=example, description: "#master"} from state
>   RepositoryStateImpl{defaultBranch=refs/heads/master,branchRevisions={refs/heads/master:
>   5e7db24835bbd67df8f67ef768403b2685a6d4c9, refs/heads/staging:
>   c4eead312a950ea9393e689933728ec92a075c9c}} to state
>   RepositoryStateImpl{defaultBranch=refs/heads/master,branchRevisions={refs/heads/master:
>   5e7db24835bbd67df8f67ef768403b2685a6d4c9, refs/heads/staging:
>   c4eead312a950ea9393e689933728ec92a075c9c}}; 0 changes collected 0
>   changes reported, time spent: 7ms  [2013-11-20 21:46:12,450]   INFO
>   [rmal executor 5] -      jetbrains.buildServer.VCS - Requesting clean
>   patch: root="example" {instance id=50, parent internal id=50, parent
>   id=example, description: "#master"},
>   toVersion=5e7db24835bbd67df8f67ef768403b2685a6d4c9,
>   checkoutRules=+:=>, cleanPatch=true, buildType=Booking Log Client ::
>   Win Chrome {id=example, internal id=bt18}, buildId=6155

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a case of wrong error reporting from TeamCity side. Human-readable error is concealed and this “Low-level patch stream is closed” is shown instead. This reporting issue will be [fixed](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-31168) in the next TeamCity 8.0.6 bugfix update.

For the time being you can try to use agent-side checkout for git (Set "VCS checkout mode" under Version Control Settings to "Automatically on agent" and make sure you have git installed on the agent computer).